# Filter based on the text content of elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm fairly new to d3 and I'm trying to tweak Mike Bostock's Treemap example (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582). Below is what I want to achieve:

1) take text inputs from user via submit button;

2) find nodes (from the tree) that contain the text inputs;

3) change the background attributes of those nodes.

To make my questions simpler, is there a way to filter (subset) elements based on the text content of elements?

For example, if I have the following four p elements, can I do something like below to change the name Cathy to red?

```
d3.selectAll("p")
    .filter(function(d) { return d.text === Cathy; })
    .attr("color", "red");
```

```
<p>Alice</p>
<p>Ben</p>
<p>Cathy</p>
<p>Daniel</p>
```

Any comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the existing elements already had data bound to them, including a "text" element, that was used to set the text, your example code would work straight away (aside from quoting the string "Cathy").

If not, you only need to make a small modification -  if the actual text content of the element is not stored in the data, you'll want to use `this` to get it:

```
d3.selectAll("p")
    .filter(function(d) { return d3.select(this).text() === "Cathy"; })
    .attr("color", "red");
```

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for your answer! The later case works perfectly for me. But I'm a little bit confused by the treemap example I'm working on. I would expect your first solution would apply because each div in the treemap is created from the data. Could you kindly explain the difference between the two solutions your mentioned?